# passing array from php to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

Hello
I'm trying to pass several arrays from php to javascript. For some of them it works, for others not. I get an array of filenames and an array which contains the content of several text files.

```
    <?php
     $album="./images/text_".$benutzerLang."_album1/";
  $fileArray=lsRandom("./images/album1");
  $listTextArray=initTexts($album,$fileArray);
  $falseArray=lsRandom("./images/album2");

  print $listTextArray[0];
  ?>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var filesArray=new Array(5);
var falseArray=new Array(5);
var textListArray=new Array(5);

<?php

$i=0;
foreach($fileArray as $element){
    print 'filesArray['.$i.']="'.$element.'";';

    $i++;
}
$i=0;
foreach($falseArray as $element){
    print 'falseArray['.$i.']="'.$element.'";';
    $i++;
}
$i=0;
foreach($listTextArray as $element){
    print 'textListArray['.$i.']="'.$element.'";';
    $i++;
}

?>

function createText(){//...
        </script>
    <?php



    function lsRandom($foldername){
   $files = array();
   $returnFiles=array();
   $indexes=array();
   $currentPath=getcwd();

   chdir($foldername);
       // Get the all files and folders in the given directory.
   $files = glob("*", GLOB_BRACE + GLOB_MARK);
   $indexes=(array_rand($files,5));
   shuffle($indexes);
   foreach($indexes as $in){
    $returnFiles[$in]=$files[$in];
   }

   chdir($currentPath);
   return $returnFiles;
    }

    function getFileText($fileName,$path){
   $filePath=''.$path.''.$fileName.'';
   //$file=fopen($filePath,'r');
   //$text=fread($file,filesize($filePath));
   $text=file_get_contents($filePath,false);
   return $text;
    }

    function initTexts($album, $images){
   $textArray1=array();
   $i=0;
   foreach($images as $im){
    $nameArray=explode(".",$im);
    $textName=''.$nameArray[0].'.txt';
    $textArray1[$i]=getFileText($textName, $album);
    $i++;
   }
   return $textArray1;
    }


    ?>
```

The problem is the $listTextArray. In the 8th row I can print the whole array $listTextArray which contains the content of some small textfiles and it works. But further down in the 'foreach - loop'. It doesn't work anymore. As soon as I use the variable $listTextArray in the second php block the rest of my php code doesn't get executed anymore. I don't know why it can not access $listTextArray at that part. Because its no problem with the other arrays $fileArray and $falseArray.

Answer (score 3):

Some general advice:

1. It's difficult to troubleshoot this kind of problem without the error message.  If no error is being printed where you can see it, look for files named `php.log`, `error.log`, or `httpd.log` or ask your server admin(s).
2. Try using [`print_r()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) on your arrays to see if there's any difference in how they're structured.  For example, just after setting the arrays in PHP:

   ```
    print_r($fileArray);
    print_r($listTextArray);
    print_r($falseArray);
   ```
3. Rather than constructing the JS arrays via loops, try using the built-in [`json_encode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function instead.  This both simplifies your PHP code and may cause more useful error messages when there are problems:

   ```
    var filesArray=<?php json_encode($fileArray) ?>;
    var falseArray=<?php json_encode($falseArray) ?>;
    var textListArray=<?php json_encode($listTextArray) ?>;
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much! the problem was probably the encoding, so by using json_encode, it solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

you initiate

```
var textListArray=new Array(5);
```

but try to use

```
listTextArray
```

Use the same name and everything will be alright

Comment: There's no mismatch — `textListArray` is being used in JS and `$listTextArray` in PHP.  Making them the same across languages might help reduce confusion, though.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is already solved for you. Use `json_encode` instead.

```
print('filesArray = '.json_encode($filesArray));
```

Note that `json_encode` *demands* that your data is utf8 encoded. But you should do that already anyway.

Comment: Thank you exactly that was the problem!